# Unable to view HTTP metrics endpoints

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

For a GKE cluster with system metrics monitoring enabled, while I'm able to view the metrics using kubectl

> kubectl get --raw /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes/$MY_NODE | jq

but I'm unable to view the same using the http endpoint the kubelet is supposed to expose the metrics, such as

> curl http://10.128.0.44:10250/metrics
> curl http://10.128.0.44:10250/metrics/cadvisor
> curl http://10.128.0.44:10250/metrics/resource

All of them time out. The I.P. address used is the internal I.P. address for the node. If the port number is wrong, is there somewhere I can see what is the port metrics are exposed on?

Comment: Are you using a private or public cluster? Which GKE version?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are making your request from a pod or VM on the same VPC as your cluster, the `/metrics` endpoint is accessible on the **read-only port (10255)** of the kubelet.

Comment: @Walking Corpse - were you able to access the metric endpoint?